# Why is code in AJAX success call is not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an AJAX script to insert data from a form to MySQL database. This is the AJAX.

```
<!-- SUBMIT FORM VIA AJAX -->
$("#f_product").on('submit',function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();

    data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo site_url('con_product/ins_product'); ?>",
    data: data
    }).success(function() {
        alert("Products list is ready to be printed");
        window.open("<?php echo site_url('con_product/print_product'); ?>","_blank");
        window.open("<?php echo site_url('con_product/form_product'); ?>","_self");
    });
});
<!-- END SUBMIT FORM VIA AJAX -->
```

The AJAX script **successfully** insert data from the form to database. But somehow, the script on success is not working. Why?

The behavior of this AJAX are:

- Insert data to database - success
- Show alert
- Open new page for print purpose.
- Refresh current page to a new form.

Comment: You have to tell us what the current and expected behavior is. We don't know what "doesn't work" implies.

Comment: well, alert is not appear. Not opening new page for print and nor refreh current page.

Comment: `done/fail/always/then` are the options that should be used off of the deferred.  `success` would be used as a parameter to the ajax.

Comment: check browser developer tools for errors

Comment: And add an errror handler since calls are not always success.

Comment: Sounds to me that it doesn't call successfully - but managed to get whatever data you're sending it into the db before it failed...

Comment: Note also that the `window.open()` calls are likely to be blocked by the browser's popup blocker.

Answer (score 3):

The `success` is the name of the `callback` function and not the `promise`.

You should use:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo site_url('con_product/ins_product'); ?>",
    data: data,
    success: function() {
        alert("Products list is ready to be printed");
        window.open("<?php echo site_url('con_product/print_product'); ?>","_blank");
        window.open("<?php echo site_url('con_product/form_product'); ?>","_self");
    }
});
```

Or the `done` promise:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo site_url('con_product/ins_product'); ?>",
    data: data
}).done(function() {
    alert("Products list is ready to be printed");
    window.open("<?php echo site_url('con_product/print_product'); ?>","_blank");
    window.open("<?php echo site_url('con_product/form_product'); ?>","_self");
});
```

Comment: I use firebug and it says jquery undefined. jquery.form.js

Comment: So if you don't have jquery you can't use it :) make sure you loaded the jquery library from the right path.

Comment: but why the data is inserted properly?

Comment: perhaps you have some other error somewhere else in your code and it caused you this

Comment: @ashura91 Since you don't have jQuery loaded, `$("#f_product").on('submit',function(event){` doesn't do anything, so you're getting normal form submission. I assume the form's `action` URL is the same one you're sending the AJAX request to.

Comment: It turns out that i have conflict in my jquery. so, I need to use another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is `.success` function. But you can try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo site_url('con_product/ins_product'); ?>",
    data: data,
    success: function(){
        alert("Products list is ready to be printed");
        window.open("<?php echo site_url('con_product/print_product'); ?>","_blank");
        window.open("<?php echo site_url('con_product/form_product'); ?>","_self");
    }
});
```

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: @Dekel - Upon checking of the documentation, there is, but not anymore recommended because that feature is already deprecated

Answer (score 0):

According to http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

What if your replace `success` with `done`?

Otherwise, `success` should be a property of the object you throw into `$.ajax({...})` with the anonymous function as its value.